# Accessing .so libraries using dlopen() throws undefined symbol error

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I'm trying to dynamically load a camera library .so file into a Linux executable to gain access to simple camera functions.

I'm attempting to do this by:

```
  if ( (newHandle = dlopen("./libCamera.so",RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL)) == NULL )
  {
     printf( "Could not open file : %s\n", dlerror() );   
     return 1;
  }
```

However this fails and I receive the following output:
    "Could not open file : libCamera.so: undefined symbol: *ZTVN10*_cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE"

How do I find out what symbols it is relying on?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Most likely, `libCamera.so` uses a symbol defined in a shared library without *depending* on that library.

1. Find a culprit. Take a real executable which links against `libCamera.so` (and it works). List its dependencies with `ldd /path/to/executable`. Among them should be a library which has a definition for `ZTVN10_cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE` (use `grep` to select likely candidates, `nm -D` on a library to be sure). That library *won't* be in the list shown by `ldd ./libCamera.so`.
2. Solve a problem. Load the library found in step 1 by `dlopen` first (use `RTLD_GLOBAL` there as well).
3. If there is a problem with another symbol, goto step 1.
4. If newly-added libraries have the same problem too, goto step 1.
5. Tell library authors to please fix their linking.

It could also happen that one of the prerequisites in `ldd ./libCamera.so` got upgraded and lost a symbol definition (maybe it was recompiled with a compiler which does name mangling differently). Then you won't find the culprit in step 1, and there is no solution but downgrading *something* again.

Answer (score 11):

The `ldd` command can be used to display shared library dependencies.

```
ldd libCamera.so
```

Once you know the dependencies, you can use `nm` to show the symbols in each library.

```
nm -DC libCamera.so
```

Comment: I saw a function listed in `nm -DC libCamera.so` but it was still undefined.  In the end it turned out that in the .h file one of the arguments was const & in the .cpp it was not const which caused it to be undefined.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. It was to do with a `.a` library, which should have been linked to my `.so` and statically linked into the archive being left out.

I determined this with (OP object name used here):

```
nm mylibrary.so | grep ZTVN10_cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE
0000ABC0 U ZTVN10_cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE
```

The `U` here [means that](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nm.html) the symbol is "undefined". You can find the demangled name of the missing object with `--demangle`:

```
 $ nm --demangle mylibrary.so | grep 0000ABC0 
0000ABC0 U abi::class_type_info(params...)
```

(or something like that) this should help you figure out which library is missing.

In my case, even after including the library on the compiler line I still had the issue. Eventually, after some tinkering I discovered that the library-file (`.a`) has to come after its dependent object (`.o`) file like:

```
g++ -Wl,-E -g -m32 ... -fPIC myobjects1.o myobjects2.o missing_library.a -shared -o mylibrary.so
```

Now I get (no more `U`):

```
 $ nm --demangle mylibrary.so | grep 0000ABC0 
0000ABC0 T abi::class_type_info(params...)
```

and most importantly I don't get the error any more!

Answer (score 1):

In your source code for libCamera.so, you have unresolved external symbol. It means that `type_infoE` have no definition in your source code and should be resolved.